# Finding all devices within range of a Pi 0 W AP

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-zero-w, communication

If my Raspberry Pi 0 W is functioning as an access point, is there a way to get a list of all the devices in range of the access point, and their relative frequencies and signal strengths? If so, how would I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean other SSID's or devices like phones/laptops etc? Fing would show other connected devices.

Comment: I'm talking about other devices, like phones/laptops/etc. And I was wondering if there was a way to get/show all devices in range of the Raspberry Pi Zero W AP, not necessarily the devices connected.